# Limit bottom border extending length of page

Tags: html, css, border

I have the following code. Jfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ugm4/). As seen, the bottom borders, what resemble `<HR>` tags extend the entire length of the page.

I would like to limit the borders of `<h1>` and `<h2>` tags to be only 30% of the page. While `<h3>` tags remain extending across the entire page. Is this possible with css?

EDIT: with a follow up question, how would I change the css on the `<h3>` tag so that under the border is roughly one line of white space the same size of the font as `<h3>`?

HTML

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Sample Wiki Page</TITLE>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type = 'text/css' href = 'default.css' />
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <DIV id='content'>
            <h3>Main Title</h3>
            <h2>Sub Title</h2>
                <p>
                     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eros odio, venenatis ut suscipit eget, vestibulum id est. Vivamus aliquet lacus sit amet enim tempus in fermentum ipsum ornare. Pellentesque tincidunt orci sed sem luctus tristique. Ut a turpis ac nisi semper luctus. Nulla mattis ornare augue, vel lacinia purus porta eu. Vestibulum pulvinar justo dolor, in ultricies tellus. Nullam semper, ante at feugiat commodo, neque eros pulvinar ante, et porttitor velit orci eu magna. Duis mattis libero vitae magna lacinia tincidunt. Vivamus placerat elit a nisi ultrices elementum. Vestibulum condimentum posuere nulla, id ornare urna mattis id. Quisque ornare risus diam. Nunc malesuada leo sit amet mauris bibendum pharetra. Integer convallis orci id lorem volutpat suscipit.

                    Vestibulum ac magna libero, non condimentum neque. Integer vestibulum, quam at tempus fermentum, mi odio dictum nibh, quis venenatis velit ligula laoreet massa. Fusce lobortis augue eu ante bibendum consequat eget posuere neque. Mauris dui lorem, fringilla et auctor a, eleifend id nisi. Sed nunc tortor, blandit et malesuada quis, posuere pellentesque lorem. Nunc vehicula lectus eget tortor tempus sed pharetra diam luctus. Aenean odio leo, accumsan a vestibulum ut, tincidunt in mi. Curabitur commodo venenatis dolor, ultrices placerat nibh tempor nec. Duis eget odio mi, id imperdiet lectus. Aenean luctus bibendum arcu non egestas.
                </p>
            <h2>Code Section</h2>
            <pre>
                <xmp>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Sample Wiki Page</TITLE>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type = 'text/css' href = 'default.css' />
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <h3>Main Title</h3>
        <h2>Sub Title</h2>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eros odio, venenatis ut
             suscipit eget, vestibulum id est. Vivamus aliquet lacus sit amet enim tempus in fermentum 
             ipsum ornare. Pellentesque tincidunt orci sed sem luctus tristique. Ut a turpis ac nisi 
             semper luctus. Nulla mattis ornare augue, vel lacinia purus porta eu. Vestibulum pulvinar 
             justo dolor, in ultricies tellus. Nullam semper, ante at feugiat commodo, neque eros 
             pulvinar ante, et porttitor velit orci eu magna. Duis mattis libero vitae magna lacinia 
             tincidunt. Vivamus placerat elit a nisi ultrices elementum. Vestibulum condimentum posuere 
             nulla, id ornare urna mattis id. Quisque ornare risus diam. Nunc malesuada leo sit amet 
             mauris bibendum pharetra. Integer convallis orci id lorem volutpat suscipit.

            Vestibulum ac magna libero, non condimentum neque. Integer vestibulum, quam at tempus 
            fermentum, mi odio dictum nibh, quis venenatis velit ligula laoreet massa. Fusce lobortis 
            augue eu ante bibendum consequat eget posuere neque. Mauris dui lorem, fringilla et auctor 
            a, eleifend id nisi. Sed nunc tortor, blandit et malesuada quis, posuere pellentesque lorem
            . Nunc vehicula lectus eget tortor tempus sed pharetra diam luctus. Aenean odio leo, 
            accumsan a vestibulum ut, tincidunt in mi. Curabitur commodo venenatis dolor, ultrices 
            placerat nibh tempor nec. Duis eget odio mi, id imperdiet lectus. Aenean luctus bibendum 
            arcu non egestas.
        <h2>Code Section</h2>
        <pre>
        </pre>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
            </xmp>
            </pre>
        </DIV>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

CSS

```
#content pre {
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px dashed #2f6fab;
    color: black;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    white-space: pre;
    margin: 1em 0px;
    display: block;
    font-family: monospace,Courier;
    line-height: 1.1em;
    width:70%;
}

#content h3{
    font-size: 188%;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    color: black;
    background: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: .5em;
    padding-bottom: .17em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}
#content h1, h2 {
    color: black;
    background: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: .5em;
    padding-bottom: .17em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `width: 30%` for your first question, and `margin-bottom: 1.2em` for your second.

Here is your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2JLFr/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. http://jsfiddle.net/n5qRS/1/

```
<h1><span>Hello World</span></h1>
```

**css**

```
h1 span {
   color: black;
   background: none;
   font-weight: normal;
   margin: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding-top: .5em;
   padding-bottom: .17em;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa; 
   display: block;
   width: 30%;
}
```

as for the second question, add a margin bottom to the h3 the same as the line height of the h3.

Comment: That's perfect, I didn't realize it would be so easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is very odd that you are having your `h3` as a the Main Title and `h2` as the subtitle (that is reversed of how it "should" be). [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ugm4/2/) uses pseudo-elements to get the border.

```
#content h1:after, h2:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 30%;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;   
}
```

The `margin-bottom` is added in that fiddle to the `h3` for your follow-up.